# Polynomial roots and their reciprocals

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

Consider the polynomial:

$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$

The value of the summation of the reciprocals of the roots of the equation is:
$\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i}}=\dfrac{-F'(0)}{F(0)}=\dfrac{-a_1}{a_0}$

The value of the product of all the roots is: $r_i\cdot r_j\cdot r_k\cdots r_n=\dfrac{(-1)^na_0}{a_n}$

Therefore, $\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_{i} \cdot r_{j}\cdot r_{k}\cdots r_n}}=\dfrac{(-1)^{-n}a_n}{a_0}$

Is it then safe to say from observation that:

$\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i\cdot r_j}}=\dfrac{a_2}{a_0}$

And, $\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i\cdot r_j\cdot r_k}}=\dfrac{-a_3}{a_0}$ and so on?

Comment: Cf. [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)

Comment: If $r_1,\dots, r_n$ are the roots of $a_0x^n+\dots+a_n$ then $\frac{1}{r_1},\dots,\frac{1}{r_n}$ are the roors of $a_nx^n+\dots+a_0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Could these properties could be extended to trigonometric functions with defined Weirestrass factorizations like sin and cos?

Comment: Do you mean saying that since $$\frac{\sin \pi z}{\pi z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}z^{2n}$$ and its roots are all integers except $0$, that $$\sum_{n\ne 0} \frac 1n = -\frac 01 = 0?$$ Yes, and no. $\sum_{n\ne 0} \frac 1n$ does not converge, as neither the sum over positives nor the sum over negatives converge. However, if you have a similar sum that you can show converges, it should converge to the value obtained this way. And for looser definitions of convergence, such as Cesaro or Cauchy Principle Value (which does converge here), the value should match as well.

Comment: Thank you :) I wasn't trying to break mathematical rules I swear :) 
$$\cdot$$
I was wondering if I could use these Vieta's formulae on the cosine function instead, to derive the Basel problem's answer. I could do it, here is the link to my "proof": https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4769685 , however I feel that I've broken some fundamental rule of logic by assuming cosine function to be a polynomial. Could such a flimsy proof ever be made valid and rigorous?

Comment: Alas, you have broken the rules there, in that your derivation involves many non-converging sums, and you've even separated them into separate sums for the negatives and positives, which denies you the ability to even claim that you are talking about the Cauchy Principle Value. So, you've fallen strictly on the "No" side of my "Yes and No".

Comment: And as an additional comment on rearranging the way an infinite sum is added up, you can only do that when the sum is absolutely convergent (i.e., if you take the absolute value of the terms, and add them all up, the series still converges). If that isn't true, and if the limit of the sequence of terms is $0$, it is possible to rearrange the order in which the summands are added so that it converges to anything you choose. For example, famously, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac 1n = \ln 2$, but  I can rearrange the terms to make it sum to $7$ instead.

Comment: All I have to do is just add up positive terms until it exceeds $7$. Then I start adding the negative terms until is drops below $7$ again. Then I switch back to the positives until it gets over $7$ again, etc. Since both the sum of the just the positive terms is $\infty$, and the sum of the negative terms is $-\infty$, I am guaranteed to always be able to keep moving past $7$ in either direction, and the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1n = 0$ guarantees the back-and-forth sum must converge.

Comment: Wonderfully put. I'll have to research about the Cauchy principle value though :) Infinite summations seem so intuitive and yet are so deceptive :(

Comment: The CPV is the limit when you approach from all directions equally fast. In the case of the limit for $\frac {\sin x}x$ I gave above, or the limits for $\cos x$ you used in the other thread, these summations are from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, and it means you are approaching both infinities equally: $$\text{(CPV)}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n = \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N a_n$$ while the normal definition of the summation is a double limit:$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n =  \lim_{(N,M)\to (\infty, -\infty)} \sum_{n=M}^N a_n$$ The balanced approach may allow the infinities to cancel.